# Rails - Route changed on it's own

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Yesterday, I had this line in my form.

```
%p= link_to "Reply", comment_reply_path(comment), :method => :get, :remote => true
```

And it worked fine. However, today when I started my rails site, I got an undefined method error and I had to change my code to.

```
reply_comment_path(comment)
```

My routes.rb contains

```
resources :comments, :only => [:create, :destroy] do
    get :reply, on: :member
end
```

Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: Unlikely that a route changed all by itself. You may wish to re-examine your assumptions.

Comment: it could be a human error,  check the routes again .

Answer (score 2):

It is because yesterday you had

```
#routes.rb
resources :comments, :only => [:create, :destroy] do
  get :reply
end
```

this will create a prefix of `comment_reply` so that `comment_reply_path(comment)` worked just fine.

But now since you have added `on: :member`, the prefix changes to `reply_comment` so you should use `reply_comment_path(comment)`.

Comment: Woah this is the Chance to Break Your 4digitz Reputation